# How to invoke methods from Controller when some of them are void and some are not?

Tags: c#

I am a student and I am currently preparing for my OOP Basics Exam.

When in the controller you have methods which return a value and such that are void - how do you invoke them without using a if-else statement?

In my code "status" is the only one which should return a string to be printed on the Console - the others are void. So I put a if-esle and 2 methods in the CommandHandler.

Since I know "if-else" is a code smell, is there a more High Quality approach to deal with the situation?

```
    if (commandName == "status")
    {
        this.Writer.WriteLine(this.CommandHandler.ExecuteStatusCommand(commandName));
    }
    else
    {
        this.CommandHandler.ExecuteCommand(commandName, commandParameters);
    }
```

This is the [project](https://github.com/MiBuena/CSharpOOPBasics/blob/master/CSharpOOPBasicsExamBlobs20Dec2015Morning/Core/Engine.cs).

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is or what is being asked here.

Comment: if "if-else" was bad code-smell, pretty much all real-world code would stink

Comment: If all you're trying to do is get away from if-else logic, a switch > case statement would do? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx  use default for the void.

Comment: @beeker that's just moving the 'issue' from one bucket to another.  it's the same "code smell"

Comment: Well, when in your controller some methods return a value and others don't - what is the most high quality approach to invoke them? I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Agreed but, only statement was to not use 'if-else' so...

Comment: @MiBuena, is there a rule that every method that gets invoked has to have the same return type or something? Using an if/else for conditional logic is what it's meant for. If one branch writes out a status and another doesn't, that's not really an issue that needs fixing. IMO at least, maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: @Brandon The methods that return something - always return a string. But here is the thing - in this case I have only 1 method - returning something "Status();" What if I had 20 methods returning and 20 not returning - how do I deal with this? I can't put each in a if-else.

Comment: Why not get rid of IF and instead just pass null for parameters in the second case?

Comment: You could get rid of ExecuteStatusCommand and call all commands through ExecuteCommand. Make ExecuteCommand return a string. Commands that need to display output would return the string to output and the other commands would return string.Empty. Then you would just check the return value and if it isn't string.IsNullOrEmpty(), then write it to the output. Another option would be to move the writing of the output into the command.

Comment: @Marc, thank you for your advice, but 2 problems here: 1. For the second suggestion - if one method does something and then also writes to the Console - this is 2 things - a method must do only 1 thing - violates the HQ Principles. 2. For the first option - is it in accordance with the HQ Principles to return string.Empty and the again use if-else? I am sorry for the questions, but I am still a student and I am trying to figure out how to write as clean as possible.

Comment: if/else is fine. This is an exact duplicate of "I don't actually have a problem, but I feel squicky because of a vague impression I got from something I misread, and/or my prof is nuts. BTW I've been programming for six weeks, if you hadn't guessed".

Comment: @Ed Plunkett - In this case it is 1 method, but what about if I had 10 or more methods returning something - put them all in a if-else like this with their names?

Comment: @MiBuena "if one method does something and then also writes to the Console - this is 2 things - a method must do only 1 thing" -- if you're relating to these vague and highly abstract "HQ principles" on that level, you need to worry about them a lot less until you have a better sense of what matters and what doesn't, based on practical experience. I've never heard of HQ, but no doubt it's got some worth as rules of thumb, tempered by experience. This isn't religion. It's general contracting, with occasional overtones of engineering.

Comment: @MiBuena Are you telling me that if 100 if/elses in a row are a bad idea, therefore inductively 99 is equally bad, all the way down to one? That's preposterous. If it gets unmanageable, do it some other way. 10 is past my threshold. A single if/else is not. This is not a religion. Anybody who told you if/else is a "code smell" is feeding you nonsense, and is more than likely incompetent. This "HQ Programming" thing has a "methodology smell", if you like.

Comment: @EdPlunkett this particular principle is the first of the SOLID Principles for High Quality Code - S - for Single Responsibility. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design) Anyway, I do agree with you that good applicable code is a combination of practice and principles from the classroom. To cut the discussion - in this case you suggest I keep it like that and if I have another method returning string - I just add if(commandName == "whatever") ... Do I understand correct?

Comment: @MiBuena So, does `this.CommandHandler.ExecuteCommand` return the value returned by the command, and `null` if the command returns nothing? I'd think about `var r = CommandHandler.ExecuteCommand(name, params); if (r != null) { Writer.WriteLine(r); }`. Then you don't need to worry about adding special cases here when you add commands elsewhere. If there's any smell at all here it's that, not the if/else.

Comment: A function doing "one thing" is a good idea, for appropriate values of "one thing". Just because the guy who wrote that may have meant something meaningful by it (and I think there's a good chance he did), doesn't mean the words he used got the whole picture from his head into yours. There's a map/territory thing here. You can't really grok this stuff until you've lived with the concrete details day in and day out for a few years. Trouble is, your immediate concern is acing the exam, not writing good code. If you're being graded on regurgitating HQ terminology, suck it up and regurgitate.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, thank you for your advice on the topic. I though about your solution to check if it returns null or string and print if it is string, but I was also hesitating again because of the if-else. Still your suggestion is better that what I wrote. So if you want to you can post it as an answer. I will wait a few days. If no better suggestions come up I will choose it as best answer. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't worry about if/else. If anybody tells you if/else is a code smell, put it through the Translator: What comes out is he's telling you he's too crazy, clueless, and/or fanatical to be taken seriously.

If by ill chance you get an instructor who requires you to say the Earth is flat to get an A, sure, tell him the Earth is flat. But if you're planning on a career or even a hobby as a navigator, don't ever forget that it's actually round.

So. It sounds to me like `CommandHandler.ExecuteStatusCommand()` executes the named command, which is implemented as a method somewhere. If the command method is `void`, `ExecuteStatusCommand()` returns `null`. Otherwise, the command method may return a string, in which case you want to write it to what looks like a stream.

OK, so one approach here is to say "A command is implemented via a method that takes a parameter and returns either null or a string representing a status. If it returns anything but null, write that to the stream".

This is standard stuff: You're defining a "contract". It's not at all inappropriate for command methods which actually return nothing to have a `String` return type, because they're fulfilling the terms of contract. "Return a string" is an option that's open to all commands; some take advantage, some don't.

This allows knowledge of the command's internals to be limited to the command method itself, which is a huge advantage. You don't need to worry about special cases at the point where you call the methods. The code below doesn't need to know which commands return a status and which don't. The commands themselves are given a means to communicate that information back to the caller, so only they need to know. It's incredibly beneficial to have a design which allows different parts of your code not to care about the details of other parts. Clean "interfaces" like this make that possible. The calling code gets simpler and stays simpler. Less code, with less need to change it over time, means less effort and fewer bugs.

As you noted, if you've got a "status" command that prints a result, and then later on you add a "print" command that also prints a result, you've got to not only implement the print command itself, but you've also got to remember to return to this part of your code and add a special case branch to the if/else.

That kind of tedious error-prone PITA is **exactly** the kind of nonsense OOP is meant to eliminate. If a new feature can be added without making a single edit to existing code, that's a sort of Platonic ideal of OOP.

So if `ExecuteCommand()` returns void, we'll want to be calling `ExecuteStatusCommand()` instead. I'm guessing at some things here. It would have been helpful if you had sketched out the semantics of those two methods.

```
var result = this.CommandHandler.ExecuteCommand(commandName, commandParameters);

if (result != null)
{
    this.Writer.WriteLine(result);
}
```

If my assumptions about your design are accurate, that's the whole deal. `commandParameters`, like the status result, are an optional part of the contract. There's nothing inherently wrong with if/else, but sometimes you don't need one.